# How to manage a while-the-server-runs secret using PHP?

Tags: php, security, encryption

I probably need to protect a LAMP based server against being stolen or hijacked by a third party.

My idea is to use hard encryption to encrypt all data records using a master key, which can't be recovered, if the server shuts down. Thus, the master key can't be stored in the file system.

I'd provide the master key using a secure channel if the server runs.

The server should be able to use it, as long as it continues to run. If the server fails, the key should not be recoverable.

What would be the best solution in this case (shared memory?).

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to protect a physical server against theft?

Comment: so you want to protect data from people that have physical access to your server?

Comment: So if the server fails you actually want to loose all data? Or do you keep the key on a remote location and communicate it over a secure channel?

Comment: @Joe Hopfgartner: Yes. Protection against physical access.

Comment: Build the cabinet with small amount of C4 attached to each hard drive. Set up a circuit so that when the power drawn by the server falls below a certain threshold the C4 goes off. New drives are cheap if it accidentally gets triggered.

Comment: @wimvds: No. If the server fails, I would re-provide the master key using a secure channel. I don't mind to use a constant key (at the first step).

Comment: @Rich Bradshaw: Great idea! Please provide a working solution, which ensures, that the C4 does not damage the servers above and below in the same rack or the racks left and right. Additionally, shouldn't be possible to damage the admins.

Comment: Ah, requirements have changed already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide more details on the kind of application and what data needs to be protected.

A pretty common way is:

- run a standard linux distribution
- have a root password and/or restrict login to ssh only
- ssh into it when they system is up
- mount the encrypted drives (provide the keyfiles over ssh or something, but only temporarily - delete them afterwars - you can have a script for that that downloads from an external sftp server that you can activate/deactive for the process)
- when the server stops (power down etc) the drives get dismounted and the data is safe
- when the server runs there is no way of getting to the data
- additional chassies intrusion can be set up but is not really necessary and can be worked around by by a trained technician that really wants to

edit:

it is theoretically possible - with perfect knowledge of all involved chips and extremly high sensitive equipment to physically hijack into live conductor paths and catch some data. (i once saw a demonstration on ata-33 PATA cables.

the server would have to be put on a mobile power supply and brought into a fully equipped lab for that.

but you can totally avoid that if you have a system level encryption layer. theres no equipment on earth that can do somthing then.

Comment: of course you can do that if memory suffices. however if thre is a system level encryption the data from the disk won't be of any use.

Comment: btw i know some cases of data phorensics at court. sadly enough in my country a sufficient protection wouldbe a filesystem that can't be read out of the box by windows xp :P

Comment: and i am serios i am not joking.

Comment: and those are the very same people that make laws about internet security and privacy

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you are trying to protect a physical server against theft?  If so, I suggest that beyond the operating system's built-in security, the primary mechanism for physical security is not code-based at all, but rather a good old fashioned lock and key.  Wonky home-brewed encryption mechanisms are not the answer - security through obscurity is **not** security.

Comment: Upvote, but: No, not against theft. The server is highly physically protected using various physical components. Multi level access control etc. I'd like to ensure, that an app can access certain data iff. an authorized person provides a master key during at a certain point. After this, it should continue to run and be able to use the encrypted data. If the system fails and gets rebooted, no data access should be possible. Until the master key get passed along again.

Comment: i don't agree. any form of physical protection can be broken. software solutions can be much safer.

Comment: @Joe - Any form of software protection can be broken.  There's nothing to disagree with - obscurity != security.